# jquery each loop dom operations (JSON)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, dom

I have a problem with function based on each loop. I am beginner and I havent find my answer on other topics.

I have function like this:

```
 function treeToCloud() {

        $(".treelist .treeimage").each(function(){   

            idCloudImage = $(".cloud-img img").attr("class");
            cloudImage = $(".cloud-img img");          

            if($(this).attr("id") == idCloudImage) {
                var treeImage = $(this).attr("src");
                $(cloudImage).attr("src", treeImage);
            }                        
        });                   

}
```

HTML like this:

```
<div class="treelist">
    <div class="treeImgContainer">
        <img src="images/del-img2.png" class="deleteTreeImage">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" id="231" class="treeimage">
    </div>
    <div class="treeImgContainer">
        <img src="images/del-img2.png" class="deleteTreeImage">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" id="21" class="treeimage">
    </div>

    <div class="treeImgContainer">
        <img src="images/del-img2.png" class="deleteTreeImage">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" id="44" class="treeimage">
    </div>
    <div class="treeImgContainer">
        <img src="images/del-img2.png" class="deleteTreeImage">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" id="45" class="treeimage">
    </div>
    <div class="treeImgContainer">
        <img src="images/del-img2.png" class="deleteTreeImage">
        <img src="images/5.jpg" id="46" class="treeimage">
    </div>
    <div class="treeImgContainer">
        <img src="images/del-img2.png" class="deleteTreeImage">
        <img src="images/6.jpg" id="441" class="treeimage"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

second part HTML:

```
<div class="say-item cloud">
    <div class="cloud-img">
        <img src="images/addci.jpg" class="45">
    </div>
        <div class="cloud-img">
        <img src="images/addci.jpg" class="46">
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON like this:

```
{
  "images": [
   {
     "id": "231",
     "uri": "images/1.jpg"
   },
   {

     "id": "21",
     "uri": "images/2.jpg"
   },
   {
     "id": "44",
     "uri": "images/3.jpg"
   },
   {
     "id": "45",
     "uri": "images/4.jpg"
   },
   {
     "id": "46",
     "uri": "images/5.jpg"
   },
   {
     "id": "441",
     "uri": "images/6.jpg"
   }
 ]
}
```

second JSON (part) like this:

```
   {
     "iconId": "45"
   },
   {
     "iconId": "46"
   }
```

And now. I have add all id's with JSON load using `.attr("id")` (working correctly). JSON id is in `.treelist` class and second JSON ("iconId") into selectors in `.cloud` class.

Now I need to compare them and if id in ".treelist" is the same like id in ".cloud" class I want to give for `.cloud img` source like is in the same id in .treelist.

I have created function, but it is changing only one (first) element and stops.

I need your help with this because I dont understand why it not working correctly

Thanks, Fantazy

Comment: If the “Second part HTML” is in the same document as the first part, then your IDs are invalid because they have to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function treeToCloud() {

    $(".treelist .treeimage").each(function(){   

        var currentTree = $(this);
        $(".cloud .cloud-img").each(function(){ 
            idCloudImage = $(this).find("img").attr("id");
            cloudImage = $(this).find("img");          

            if($(currentTree).attr("id") == idCloudImage) {
                var treeImage = $(currentTree).attr("src");
                $(cloudImage).attr("src", treeImage);
            }     
        });

    });                   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code

```
  function treeToCloud() {
    $(".treelist .treeimage").each(function(){   
        var firstId = $(this).attr("id");
          $(".cloud-img img").each(function(){
             var secondId = $(this).attr("id");
             if(firstId  == secondId ) {
                $(this).attr("src", treeImage);
             }    
        });           
    });                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! vijayP solved my problem ! :)

Urvi - thanks, but Your code not working

Final code:

```
function treeToCloud() {

    $(".treelist .treeimage").each(function(){   

        var currentTree = $(this);
        $(".cloud .cloud-img").each(function(){ 
            idCloudImage = $(this).find("img").attr("class");
            cloudImage = $(this).find("img");          

            if($(currentTree).attr("id") == idCloudImage) {
                var treeImage = $(currentTree).attr("src");
                $(cloudImage).attr("src", treeImage);
            }     
        });

    });                   

}
```